# Plotting a Gaussian in Python

Tags: normal-distribution, python, histogram, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a histogram of my data, and I seem to be a little confused here. I am using matplotlib in Python. Here is the code from their website:

```
mu = 100 #mean
sigma = 15 #std deviation
x = mu + sigma * np.random.randn(10000)

# the histogram of the data
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
```

I am confused as to what the *x*-axis should be for my use. I have calculated the standard deviation and the mean, but I am uncertain if I should replace the `np.random.randn(10000)` with the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to do is completely replace `x` in the plotting function with your data, so what you should get looks like this:

```
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(my_data, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Also, if you aren't planning on using `n`, `bins`, or `patches` you can discard them by just running:

```
plt.hist(my_data, num_bins, normed=1, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

If this isn't correct please let me know and I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Did everything work out for you?

Comment: yes, I am able to interpret my data now. Just one last question, when I plot this, what will go on the y-axis? It looks like it may be what portion of my data a certain bin will fall in.

Comment: Because you have `normed=1` matplotlib will normalize the y-axis to represent what percentage of your data fell in that bin. If you want the counts for each bin you can simply remove the whole normed argument.

Comment: I see. this makes sense. My data is just looking odd. Median ~29 and mean~119

Comment: I looked into it and my above comment is incorrect. From the [Numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html#numpy.histogram)

>  If True, the result is the value of the probability density function at the bin, normalized such that the integral over the range is 1

Answer (score 1):

The code you proposed for generating random numbers will not generate a distribution centered on `mean` and with a standard deviation `sigma`, as your variable names suggest. Note that if you calculate using

```
np.std(np.random.randn(10000))
```

you'll get something around 0.28 and the reason is simple: `np.random.randn(k)` draws `k` numbers between 0 and 1. To generate a vector with 10 000 numbers following a gaussian distribution of parameters `mu` and `sigma` use

```
from random import gauss
x=[gauss(mu, sigma) for i in range(10000)]
```

for which in the last line I used the "pythonic" condensed version of a for loop, the [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-pythong). Then you can feed your `x` vector to the `histogram` plotting routine, that will calculate the histogram of a vector for plotting.